# Remove Extra Space At End

Tags: java

I wrote this in Java, and I want the output such that it creates a space after every value except for the last one. How do I get it to show up like `1[]2[]3[]4[]5[]6[]7` rather than `1[]2[]3[]4[]5[]6[]7[]` ?

Here is my code!

```
public class Pentagonal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, x, n1;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        n = input.nextInt();

        n1 = 1;

        System.out.print("The pentagonal numbers are: ");

        while (n1 <= n) {
            x = (3 * n1 * n1 - n1) / 2;
            if (n1 == n)
                System.out.print(x);
            else
                System.out.print(x + " ");
            n1++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's hard to read code like this.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like the code should work. Try debugging it and inspect the variables to find out why it's not executing the no-space output

Comment: That is the problem, i can't figure out what is causing the extra indentation...

Comment: be more specific what is your problem?

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem at all.  My IDE's output is told to print out whitespace along with it, so I changed your space to tab, and it doesn't show anything trailing at the end.  Do you have some sample output that would show this behavior?

Comment: it works for me - Enter an integer: 5
The pentagonal numbers are: 1 5 12 22 35(no space here)

Comment: Okay, so when i run this it prints an extra space at the end of the output. It looks like this 1[]2[]3[]4[]5[] (the brackets are spaces) and I want it to look like this: 1[]2[]3[]4[]5. Does my question make better sense?

Comment: What makes you think you have an extra space? I don't get the extra space at the end when I run it

Comment: The code you have posted does not exhibit the behavior you describe.

Comment: `The pentagonal numbers are: 1 5 12 22 35BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. No space between `35` and `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`

Comment: @Octopus try putting a "." inside else statement i have, you will see what i mean about the extra space.

Comment: **Still** not seeing the behavior.  Nothing in the code suggests that you'd be adding a space after the last element, either.

Comment: according to my teacher's "grading compiler", it says that my code displays that? Could there be a better way in writing this?

Comment: Have you asked any of your peers if they're having similar issues?

Comment: _"..try putting a "." inside else statement i have"_ `The pentagonal numbers are: 1.5.12.22.35BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. No `.`

Comment: Same here, the output seems correct. Are you sure you are running the same code posted?

Comment: @PakkuDon it is an online class and the teacher doesn't ever want to be bothered because he has about 10 classes this semester.

Comment: It works for me, what is the problem. Not getting spaces.

Comment: Is it possible the online grader is rejecting something else and not what you think it is?

Comment: Did some testing: Enter an integer: 5
The pentagonal numbers are: 1s5s12s22s35. No "s" after the last.

Comment: Well, here is the new error log:


Your output has right initial contents, but is missing 1 characters at end
You have only a First Line Error

sdiff side by side difference your output versus solution....
Enter an integer: The pentagonal numbers are: 1 5 12 22 35    \ Enter an integer: The pentagonal numbers are: 1 5 12 22 35

Comment: Missing a character? Is it expecting a \n?

Comment: Try adding a println("") at the end of the program...maybe the grader is LOOKING for a newline, and is showing it as whitespace?

Comment: @PakkuDon no. i tried a newline, it does not work.

Comment: @TonyK. no, i tried... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. I see no problem with it. Just check this out

```
 while (n1 <= n) {
    x = (3 * n1 * n1 - n1) / 2;
    System.out.print(x + ((n1 == n) ? "\n" : " "));
    n1++;
}
```

Replace this `"\n"`(new line) with `" "` (space) if you want!

Comment: YES! THIS WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH! 
i wish i can give you rep points :(

Comment: @user3126496 if an answer works for you, you should accept it (The check mark below the down vote). That way an future passersby of this question will know which one is more suitable for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just Add the following line after while loop

```
System.out.print("\b");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(n1==n)
    System.out.print(x);
else
    if(n1 != n-1) {
        System.out.print(x+" ");
    } else {
        System.out.print(x);
    }
n1++;
```